# visualising more than 3 dimensions

Tags: data-visualization, high-dimensional

In my problem, I am having a lot of variables - easily 10-15
If this was a 2 dimensional data then I would plot these and visualize the plots to identify certain abnormalities.

But with so many variables, I don't know how to visualize so many variables.

Any suggestions how to think about so many variables?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to think about visualizing high-dimensional data: [tag:multidimensional-scaling], [tag:t-sne], [tag:pca], [tag:self-organizing-maps], [tag:dimensionality-reduction]. Can you clarify specifically what you are interested in knowing about your data?

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: you could use the algorithm umap for dimensionality reduction.